# Unable to copy/mirror website-page by using WinHTTrack

Tags: website, mirroring, httrack

I am using [Httrack](https://download.httrack.com/) for copying/mirroring a website and facing one problem.

I am talking about [this](http://www.engineeringdrawing.org/) website. Consider I want to cover [this](http://www.engineeringdrawing.org/category/projection_of_solids) page with all inside links (you can see like: problem 6.11 , problem 6.10 from that page). So, I've tried following:

1. Enter project name and URL:

[image: screen-shot]

2. Set option can go up and down both

[image]

And I started to mirror, the process finished but when I browse index.html, the main page displays correctly but further links (sab page as mentioned earlier problem 6.11, 6.10 etc) does not display - only the file name feed is shown.(try yourself to see what is going wrong)

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read the [FAQ](https://www.httrack.com/html/faq.html#Q0)

Here is a quote from WinHTTrack website:

> **Question: Some sites are captured very well, other aren't. Why?**
>
> Answer: There are several reasons (and solutions) for a mirror to fail. Reading the log
>   files (ans this FAQ!) is generally a VERY good idea to figure out what
>   occured.
>
> Links within the site refers to external links, or links located in another (or upper) directories, not captured by default - the use
>   of filters is generally THE solution, as this is one of the powerful
>   option in HTTrack. See the above questions/answers.
>       Website 'robots.txt' rules forbide access to several website parts - you can disable them, but only with great care!
>       HTTrack is filtered (by its default User-agent IDentity) - you can change the Browser User-Agent identity to an anonymous one (MSIE,
>   Netscape..) - here again, use this option with care, as this measure
>   might have been put to avoid some bandwidth abuse (see also the abuse
>   faq!)
>
> There are cases, however, that can not be (yet) handled:
>
> **Flash sites** - no full support
>
> **Intensive Java/Javascript sites** - might be bogus/incomplete
>
> **Complex CGI with built-in redirect, and other tricks** - very complicated to handle, and therefore might cause problems
>
> Parsing problem in the HTML code (cases where the engine is fooled, for example by a false comment (
>
> comment (-->) detected. Rare cases, but might occur. A bug report is
>   then generally good!
>
> Note: For some sites, setting "Force old HTTP/1.0 requests" option can
>   be useful, as this option uses more basic requests (no HEAD request
>   for example). This will cause a performance loss, but will increase
>   the compatibility with some cgi-based sites.

PD. There are many reasons to website cant be captured 100% i think in SuperUser we are very enthusiast but we wont to make reverse enginerring to a website to discovery which system is running from behind(*It's my oppinion*).